# How authorize for multiple user on Policies in laravel?

Tags: authorization, laravel-8, policy

Hello i'm trying to authorize 2 differents users to view one of my pages.

On the Policy's view function i passed my two users, and it doesn't worked.

I've tried many ways.

```
public function view(User $user, Proposal $proposal)
{
    return $user->id === $proposal->user_id;
    return $user->id === $proposal->annonce->user->id;
           
}

public function view(User $user, Proposal $proposal)
{
    return $user->id === $proposal->user_id; $proposal->annonce->user->id;
              
}

public function view(User $user, Proposal $proposal)
{
    $good_user = $proposal->user_id; $proposal->annonce->user->id;
    return $user->id === $good_user;
              
}
```

Problem is, in my view the `@can(show, $proposal)`, only authorize the first user i've write on the policy, never the second. Have you got some ideas i could try?

Answer (score 1):

I finally find an answer. I put it here, hoping, one day, it will help someone.

```
if($user->id === $proposal->user_id) {
        return true;
    } elseif($user->id === $proposal->annonce->user->id) {
        return true;
    }
```

Don't know if it's the best way, but it works ^^